# JavaFX - Painting on canvas in second thread

Tags: multithreading, canvas, javafx, repaint

I have code:

```
public void repaint()
{
   int i;

   for(i=0; i<4; i++)
   {
      Thread thread = new Thread()
      {
         @Override
         public void run()
         {
            System.out.println("BEFORE PAINT");
            paint(); //my own function for painting on Canvas
         }
      };

      thread.setPriority(MAX_PRIORITY);
      thread.start();

      while(thread.isAlive())
      {
         sleep(1000);
         System.out.println("PAINTING");
      }
   }
}
```

I want to repaint my canvas in each cycle of for cycle.

Output in console:

BEFORE PAINT

PAINTING

BEFORE PAINT

PAINTING

BEFORE PAINT

PAINTING

BEFORE PAINT

PAINTING

But in this case is canvas repaint after returning from function repaint()!!!. What I do wrong??

Thank you for yours answers!!

Comment: Why would you do such terrible things to Java? ;<

Comment: I don't understand what is terrible on this??

Comment: Painting from other threads.

Comment: Do you need this for a game? There exists other approaches to implement a game loop in JavaFX, e. g. [Using the JavaFX AnimationTimer](http://blog.netopyr.com/2012/06/14/using-the-javafx-animationtimer/)

Comment: If I know that canvas don't have any function as refresh() or flush() for immediately repainting, and this is solution which I found on various webs.

Comment: Quoting the **first** sentence in the [JavaFX official tutorial on concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm): "The JavaFX scene graph, which represents the graphical user interface of a JavaFX application, is not thread-safe and can only be accessed and modified from the UI thread also known as the JavaFX Application thread."

Comment: @user3816584 What about the thread-safe `repaint()` method?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know any thread-safe repaint() method. Could you explain It to me please??